# Why did this script stop working?

Tags: mariadb

I am running the database via the mariadb:lts docker image. Initially the code executes some scripts that restore the database from a dump ).sql) file and then some files to alter the database for local use. One of those scripts adds a column to a table and then populates the column for known records. This used to work just fine, but recently it started failing.

Here is the segment from the dump file that defines the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SMaLLProgramTypes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

And here is the script in question:

```
ALTER TABLE SMaLLProgramTypes ADD Abbreviation VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'x';

UPDATE SMaLLProgramTypes SET Abbreviation='RRSE' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE SMaLLProgramTypes SET Abbreviation='RRDE' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE SMaLLProgramTypes SET Abbreviation='DE' WHERE id = 3;
UPDATE SMaLLProgramTypes SET Abbreviation='SE' WHERE id = 4;

UPDATE SMaLLUsers SET Phone1=CONCAT('T:', Phone1) WHERE Phone1 RLIKE '^[0-9]+$';
UPDATE SMaLLUsers SET Phone2=CONCAT('T:', Phone2) WHERE Phone2 RLIKE '^[0-9]+$';
UPDATE SMaLLUsers SET Phone3=CONCAT('T:', Phone3) WHERE Phone3 RLIKE '^[0-9]+$';

ALTER TABLE SMaLLParticipations ADD IsCallUP Set('Yes', 'No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No';
```

And here is the error message that appears in the container log when launched with no database initialized yet:

```
2024-02-13 13:39:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0. Prepare SQL file.sql


2024-02-13 13:39:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.llontari_SMaLLSandbox_2024-02-06JD.sql


2024-02-13 13:39:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.ResetUsersForDevelopment.sql


2024-02-13 13:39:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3.AdjustSeasonsAndProgramsAndGamesForDevelopment.sql
baseDate        OldestDate      OffsetInDays
2022-10-01 00:00:00     2021-07-04 00:00:00     454


2024-02-13 13:39:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4.UpdateSchema.sql
2024-02-13 13:39:11 10 [ERROR] mariadbd: Incorrect information in file: './small/smallprogramtypes.frm'
ERROR 1033 (HY000) at line 3: Incorrect information in file: './small/smallprogramtypes.frm'
```

I do not know how far back I would have to go, but this was working fine at least 6 months ago. I tried going back as far as 10.11.3, but the error is still being reported.

Any thoughts on what may have changed to prevent this from working? Or why it is failing at all?

Comment: I should note that if I do not execute teh script as part of the initialization, but execute it after the fact, then it executes without issue. The error occurs only when the script is executed as part of the initialization.

Comment: All of the files are INNODB, and the database is being initialized from the dump file with modifcations from other scripts.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  Are the `.frm` files left over?

Comment: Using the mariadb:lts docker image, and the database is being freshly restored from a dump script.

Comment: "dump script" -- dump the raw files?  `mysqldump`?  Something else?

Comment: The "dump script" is generated from the database export request from various SQL clients.

Comment: What commands are in the script?  `ALTERs` and `UPDATEs` don't sound like a "dump".

Comment: I resolved the issue!

I placed a "DO SLEEP(1);" statement between the "ALTER TABLE" and the "UPDATE" statements for the same table and the issue went away.